# What is the meaning of Hierarchical property of channel configuration in hyper ledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyper ledger and was going through the documentation to get some insight of hyperledger especially in Channel Configuration (configtx) section.

There they defined that

> Channel configuration has the following important properties:
>
> 1. Versioned: All elements of the configuration have an associated version which is advanced with every modification. Further, every
>      committed configuration receives a sequence number.
> 2. Permissioned: Each element of the configuration has an associated policy which governs whether or not modification to that element is
>      permitted. Anyone with a copy of the previous configtx (and no
>      additional info) may verify the validity of a new config based on
>      these policies.
>
>    3. Hierarchical: A root configuration group contains sub-groups, and each group of the hierarchy has associated values and policies. These
>         policies can take advantage of the hierarchy to derive policies at one
>         level from policies of lower levels.

Can somebody explain me the third point with some example?

Here is the link for above paragraph http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/configtx.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important way that the channel configuration is hierarchical has to do with policy evaluation.  There is a policy type called an "implicit meta policy".  This policy type's evaluation depends on the evaluation of policies deeper in the tree.

Take for example the `/Channel/Admins` policy.  The default value for this policy is an implicit meta policy with a rule of `MAJORITY Admins`.  This rule implies that a majority of the sub-groups must have a policy named `Admins`, which evaluates to true for the `/Channel/Admins` policy to evaluate to true.  In standard application channel, there are two sub-groups: `Application` and `Orderer`.  Each of these have an `Admins` policy which is, by default, also `MAJORITY Admins`.  The `/Channel/Application/Admins` policy will require that the `Admins` policy of each of the sub-groups evaluates to true.  These sub-groups are application organizations, each of which has a default `Admins` policy which may be satisfied by a signature from one of their admin certs.

So, the end result of this hierarchy is that to satisfy the `/Channel/Application/Admins` policy, it requires that a majority of the application organizations admins agree.  To satisfy the `/Channel/Orderer/Admins` policy, it requires a majority of the orderer organizations to agree.  And finally to satisfy the `/Channel/Admins` policy requires that both a majority of the orderer organizations and a majority of the application organizations agree.

Finally, with these policy behaviors in mind, hopefully the natural organization of the configuration as 'hierarchical' makes sense.  Configuration elements near the root of the configuration generally require agreement from the entire network to modify.  As elements get further from the root and closer to the leaves, the number of stakeholders diminishes, and modifications can be made with less agreement.  For instance, an organization may modify its own CRL or CAs without requiring agreement from any other organizations in the network.